# Interface function returning untyped value (*) while implementation return specific type?

Tags: actionscript-3

Out of curiosity I was wondering if it was possible to have an interface definition returning untyped values, while its implementations return typed value ?

For example, having the following interface :

```
interfaceExample
{
    function someExampleFunction():*
}
```

implemented the following way :

```
classA implements interfaceExample
{
    public function someExampleFunction():Int{ ... }
}


classB implements interfaceExample
{
    public function someExampleFunction():String{ ... }
}
```

( I've googled with no result, maybe I haven't been able to ask the right way )
I guess the answer is 'no it's not possible in any way, Interface aren't designed like that' -- so what could be a friendly way to achieve such a thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, this won't compile. This is because the compiler doesn't support overloading of the signature of methods from parent classes or interfaces.

If you think about it, it doesn't really make sense to override the return type when implementing an interface because the code consuming your interface API should not depend on the implementation (`int` or `String` return value).

The solution to use really depends on what you are trying to do in the end. In general, the return type should be the common denominator between the different types you could produce. This could also be **another interface** that describes what to expect from the return value.

Comment: I'll have to go for other interfaces for now, as I've replied to @JasonMc92 it was mainly for coding comfort, and I just wanted to avoid having a whole bunch of interfaces just to avoid typecasting a '*' each time I needed it...

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not heavily familiar with interface definitions, I do know that I write a lot of functions that work with typed and untyped arguments and returns.

**In the event that what you're describing is not possible**, and depending on what you're doing, I would recommend writing a simple function that can convert an untyped variable into a typed variable. They're fairly simple. Then, you could call this function to handle whatever data comes in via the interface definition.

A rough example (untested):

```
function convertDataTo(type:String, input:*):*
{
    var rI:int;
    var rN:Number;
    var rS:String;
    var rB:Boolean;

    switch(type)
    {
        case "int":
            if(isNaN(int(input))
            {
                rI = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                rI = int(input);
            }
        break;
        case "Number":
            if(isNaN(Number(input))
            {
                rN = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                rN = Number(input);
            }
        break;
        case "Boolean":
            if(input == "true")
            {
                rB = true;
            }
            else if(input == "false")
            {
                rB = false;
            }
            else
            {
                rB = Boolean(input);
            }
            return rB;
        break;
        case "String":
            rS = input.toString();
        break;
        default:
            trace("Invalid data type!");
            return 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also rewrite this function to convert from String type to any other type, and have your interface definition always return strings. On the other end, you can have a similar function that converts all variables to strings that can be interpreted by this function.

By the way, I've had to use that kind of string interpretation in writing my own scripting language for use inside one of my larger projects.

**Of course, I don't pretend this answers your question directly, but I wanted to throw out this contingency in case what you're looking for doesn't work.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's a possible workaround for sure. Since it was for a plugin API, it's a specific case were app-side I don't really care about type and could have been using '*', but on the plugin side I would have wanted a bit more coding comfort and having the same function for multiple purposes without typecasting the return value. Too bad :(